# Animate div without its pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a custom loading spinner using a single html element,

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

it should look like 3 bars scaling up and i'm adding a animation to the element and also the before and after pseudo-elements. My issue here is that when i add the animation to the actual div, the animation gets passed to the pseudo-elements as well and the scaling is twice as big for them.

```
.loader {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
  animation: grow 1s ease-in-out 0.33s infinite;
  &::after,
  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: inherit;
  }
  &::before {
    top: 0px;
    left: -15px;
    animation: grow 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  }
  &::after {
    top: 0px;
    left: 15px;
    animation: grow 1s ease-in-out 0.66s infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes grow {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the inheritance of the animation to the pseudo-elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I found out that the scale animation was at fault for being inherited downwards. I tried to rewrite the animation without the scale function and came up with something that has a similar result.

```
@keyframes grow {
  0%,
  100% {
    height: 3em;
    width: 0.75em;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 4em;
    width: 0.8em;
    box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  }
}
```

I know it doesn't have the exact same effect but it was good enough for me. Hope it helps someone.